# Prisma: Is there a way to use DATE functions in prisma without raw query?

Tags: database, postgresql, prisma, prisma2

I have the below query and was wondering if it is possible to convert it into a prisma query or would I have to use raw queries itself?

```
SELECT
EXTRACT(DAY FROM MAX(joindate) - CURRENT_DATE AS DateDifference
TO_CHAR(date_of_implementation, 'Mon') as "name",
SUM("cost_saved") as "savings" 
FROM tracker_info
```

Answer (score 2):

Currently, this is only possible via a [raw query](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/raw-database-access) but I would suggest creating a feature request [here](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=feature_request.md&title=) that allows raw function access inside Prisma API's.